NestJs - How to find by id if existing record in multiple collections (mongodb)
in mongodb, i have 4 collections to save conversations and comments from Facebook and Instagram. 4 collections is facebook_page_conversations, facebook_page_comments, instagram_conversations, instagram_comments. My questions is how to find all record with pagination and find record by id if id exists in one of 4 collections.
I don't have solution for find all record and merge it to an result.
about find by id problem, i'm trying this pseudo code to find by id using Nestjs
fb_conversation = FacebookConversationModel.findOne({ _id });
fb_comment = FacebookCommentModel.findOne({ _id });
ig_conversation = InstagramConversationModel.findOne({ _id });
ig_comment = InstagramCommentModel.findOne({ _id });

and return record if value != null.
I think this is bad solution and i am looking forward to receive help from anyone.

Four queries like you have or one aggregation (that uses three $unionWith stages) are the two most likely ways to do this

Are there any specific  reasons to have these four separate collections? Or is it a system evolved over time and now being challenged by new requirements in more performant way? Are the new requirements of queries and reporting should be on real-time basis? If real-time is not a pressing need, then how much time the queries and reports can go out of synch?
